# How to write isolinux to an ext4 filesystem

Tags: boot, ext4, sd-card

How would I write isolinux to an ext4 filesystem on an 1 GB SD card so that it would boot at startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't as a SD card normally doesn't look like a ISO image. Instead have a look at [EXTLINUX](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/EXTLINUX).

In short:

1. Mount your sd card
2. run `extlinux --install MOUNTPOINT/boot`